# Unable to update appClientId locally in Flutter using AWS Amplify

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplify-flutter

I am using AWS Amplify for Flutter. I generated many configurations using the CLI and pushed them to AWS using `amplify push`. For some reason, I had to delete the App client created using Amplify after which I manually created an app client in Cognito.

[Created App client in Cognito User Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1dMx.png)

Now I changed the **app client ID** in Flutter project to the new one(blurred in the images) in **amplifyconfiguration.dart** and **amplify-meta.json** in **backend/** directory. According to [Amplify CLI](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/files/#amplifycurrent-cloud-backend) docs, we are allowed to do manual edits to **amplify/backend**.

[amplify-meta.json change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc7EY.png)

Finally I did an `amplify push` so that these changes are deployed to Cloud too. But when I checked the amplify-meta.json in the backend/ directory, I saw that the app client ID was reverted back to the old one which I had deleted initially.

I feel this is the reason why I am not able to get the correct access token for a session, can someone please help me to know how I can update the app client ID locally??